# Allocate bikes to people - First Priority (Closest bike to closest person)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

Passing in a grid to a function with bikes and person at locations

```
[ 'c' , '_' ,'A' ,'_', '_' , '_']
[ '_' , '_' ,'a' ,'_', '_' , '_']
[ '_' , '_' ,'_' ,'_', 'b' , '_']
[ '_' , '_' ,'_' ,'_', '_' , '_']
[ 'D' , 'd' ,'_' ,'_', '_' , 'B']
[ '_' , '_' ,'_' ,'C', '_' , '_']
```

**Output:** Something like this `[A:1, B:3, C:8, D:1]`

> Where A is the person and 1 is the step required to travel to get to the bike.

**Criterias:**

1. Closest person to the bike, get the bike at the first priority.
2. Single bike can't be assigned to 2 individuals
3. Distance of a bike from one individual will never be equal to distance of the same bike from a different individual.
4. Distances can be equal, but 2 different bikes and 2 different individuals

I feel like Graphical representation might make more sense hence

[image]

---

**My Approach:**

1. Find the location of Bikes and Person and store them in an Array.

   `person = [[0,2],[4,0],[4,5],[5,3]], bikes = [[0,0],[1,2],[2,4],[4,1]];`
2. As shortest path will be 1, start removing the bikes and person from the Array 
   who has the shortest path as 1 and keep incrementing the shortest path by 1.
   And store the person and bike into results array.
3. Need to keep doing step # 2 till our Person's Array is empty

```js
function findBikesForPeople(grid) {

  let row_length = grid.length;
  let col_length = grid[0].length;
  var bikes = [],
    person = [];

  for (var row = 0; row < row_length; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < col_length; col++) {
      if (grid[row][col] === 'B') {
        bikes.push([row, col]);
      }
      if (grid[row][col] === 'P') {
        person.push([row, col]);
      }
    }
  }

  var distances = (bikes, person) => {
    var dist = [];
    person.map((single) => {
      var inner = [];
      bikes.map((bike) => {
        inner.push(check_distance(single, bike));
      })
      dist.push(inner);
    })
    return dist;
  }


  //This isn't right
  var AllocateBikes = (distances) => {
    //var result = [];
    //var min = 1;
    //var increment = 0;
    //  let people = distances.length;
    //let bikeCount = distances[0].length;
    //while (people > 0) {
    //  if (Math.min(...distances[]))
    // }
    return distances;
  }

  function check_distance(a, b) {
    return Math.abs(b[1] - a[1]) + Math.abs(b[0] - a[0]);
  }

  let distance_between = distances(bikes, person);
  console.log(AllocateBikes(distance_between));

}
var grid = [
  ['P', '_', 'B', '_', '_'],
  ['_', '_', '_', '_', 'B'],
  ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_'],
  ['_', 'P', '_', '_', '_'],
  ['_', '_', '_', '_', 'B']
];

findBikesForPeople(grid);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be `C -> d` and `D -> c`? That would be 3+4, which is better than 8+1.

Comment: No, because D->d is just 1 step, and for person D it's more convenient to approach to d than to c.

Comment: True, but it's also more convenient for C to approach d than to approach c. So I'm wondering whether you've actually presented the problem correctly.

Comment: @user3386109, that's true. But here we are assuming that it's more person centric. That if one person gets something at a closer location, he will get to pick that one. Irrelevant to other person's circumstances, in this case distance.

Comment: Exactly what *is* the goal of the algorithm?  Is it merely to have any 1:1 match-up?  Also, you've posted code, but haven't described the problem you're having.

Comment: Goals : 1. Every person get's a bike, 2. At the shortest location from the person's position and 3. No single bike is assigned to 2 people.

Comment: Do you care about finding the shortest total distance for all four people combined?  Or does each person just take the closest remaining bike?

Comment: No @JohnGordon , let me rephrase the question. As I feel it's uncomfortable for people to understand.

Comment: It's still not clear, for example, bike d is closest to both A and B, so how can we make the decision? do some people have higher priority than others? Like for your example, mapping c with D and C with d will minimise the total travel distance of c and d.

Comment: @PhamTrung, please check the update. **Criteria**, might make more sense. Sorry for being very naive in explaining the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're almost there. What you need to do is indeed find all the combinations of people and bikes, and measure their distance. Then, you sort these based on distance, and then you can iterate over them and assign the bikes to the people whenever you come across a combination where the person doesn't have a bike yet and the bike is still free. This will assign a different bike to each person, and use the shortest distances first. In javascript that could look something like:

```js
function findBikesForPeople(grid) {
    var rows = grid.length, cols = grid[0].length;
    var bikes = [], people = [];
    for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            if (grid[row][col] === 'B') {
                bikes.push({y: row, x:col});
            }
            if (grid[row][col] === 'P') {
                people.push({y:row, x:col});
            }
        }
    }
    var combis = [];
    for (var p in people) {
        for (var b in bikes) {
            var d = distance(people[p], bikes[b]);
            combis.push({person:p, bike:b, distance:d});
        }
    }
    combis.sort(function(a,b) {return a.distance - b.distance});
    var hasBike = [], isTaken = [], assignment = [];
    for (var c in combis) {
        var person = combis[c].person, bike = combis[c].bike;
        if (!hasBike[person] && !isTaken[bike]) {
            assignment.push({person:person, 
                             px:people[person].x, py:people[person].y,
                             bike:bike,
                             bx:bikes[bike].x, by:bikes[bike].y});
            hasBike[person] = true;
            isTaken[bike] = true;
        }
    }
    return assignment;

    function distance(a, b) {
        return Math.abs(b.x - a.x) + Math.abs(b.y - a.y);
    }
}

var grid = [['B', '_', 'P', '_', '_', '_'],
            ['_', '_', 'B', '_', '_', '_'],
            ['_', '_', '_', '_', 'B', '_'],
            ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'],
            ['P', 'B', '_', '_', '_', 'P'],
            ['_', '_', '_', 'P', '_', '_']];
document.write(JSON.stringify(findBikesForPeople(grid)));
```

Note: I'm interpreting the grid as displayed in the code, with x = horizontal and y = vertical, i.e. grid[y][x], with (0,0) being the top left corner.

Comment: Thank you for the time and effort, let me go through your solution. Really appreciate the work, sorry I missed to reply.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh No problem. Because you were still editing the question after we had answered, I thought we had misinterpreted it and you wanted something different.

Comment: No no, had my edit question open in my tab. So just posted with better explanation right away.

Comment: Ahh, I cleared my confusion. You've interchanged the indexes of `person`. y=x and x=y.
Rest everything is just perfect. Please verify.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh Yes, I'm interpreting the grid as shown, with x=horizontal and y=vertical, i.e. grid[y][x], with 0,0 being top left.

Comment: Ok perfect, I got the point. Thank you very much again for your time. :)

Answer (score 2):

I will outline the steps for you

1. Find the location of Bikes and Person and store them in an Array.
    `person = [[0,2],[4,0],[4,5],[5,3]], bikes = [[0,0],[1,2],[2,4],[4,1]];`
2. Define a Class ( lets call it `Distance`) having following variables: 
   `person_id: use person index (0, 1, 2, ...) 
    bike_id: use bike index (0, 1, 2, ...)
    dist: distance between this person and bike`
3. Create an array of `Distance` objects for each pair of person and bike. So for the above example you will have object values
    `[(0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 1), ...(3, 3, 3)]`
4. Sort the array by increasing value of `dist`
5. Create two Boolean arrays person_used having same number of elements as number of persons and bike_used having same number of elements as number of bikes(both initialized as false).
   `person_used = [false, false, false, false], bike_used = [false, false, false, false]`
6. Iterate through the array. If for the current `Distance` object `person_used[person_id] == false && bike_used[bike_id] == false` assign this person to this bike and set both `person_used[person_id] and bike_used[bike_id] to true`. If either is `false` you can ignore it.
7. Stop when each person is assigned a bike.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation really appreciate that, let me write down your steps into code tomorrow.